# NPM modules make Google drive chrash - how to exclude NPM modules from sync'ing?

Tags: backup, sync, google-drive, node.js

Im using google drive as my cloud based "sync/backup" service for all important work related files.

This has been working perfect and very sufficient until I started using NPM modules (node_modules) as a part of my node.js/gulp/git repo coding setup.

It seems that google drive doesn't play well when stumbling upon sync of the node_modules folder - Google Drive will simply chrash.

I [read this topic](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/HSbcOfmYudg) over at the google forums and seems like it's a genuine big problem for many people (just with other file type).

I'm wondering if anyone using NPM modules and using google drive have found a work around to have google drive ignore the NPM modules folders when sync'in, so it doesn't chrash?

Answer (score 0):

Under Preferences choose to sync specific folders.

What I did was to select everything and unselect those nasty /node_modules folders. I believe this can be automated by a script.

Comment: What's the script?